# Integrating twilio inside journey builder in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, twilio

Can someone please suggest if we can integrate twilio inside journey builder as a custom activity and use it for sms sending inside journeys. We dont have mobile connect(not using mobile studio) set up for our sfmc account as that will more on cost.
Looking for alternative for mobile connect.
If twilio sfmc integration is possible ? Has anyone done that.  please can you share steps.